# Find the Saddle Point in Python

Tags: python

I need to find the saddle point of a matrix with desire number of rows and columns in Python.
But when I enter 3 for each row and columns it just take three elements and make a 1 x 3 matrix.
Here is my code:

```
def SaddlePoint(mat, n):

for i in range(n):

    min_row = mat[i][0];
    col_ind = 0;
    for j in range(1, n):
        if (min_row > mat[i][j]):
            min_row = mat[i][j];
            col_ind = j;
    k = 0;
    for k in range(n):

        if (min_row < mat[k][col_ind]):
            break;
        k += 1;

    if (k == n):
        print("Value of Saddle Point ",
              min_row);
        return True;

return False;

if __name__ == '__main__':

row=int(input("Enter number of rows you want: "))
col=int(input("Enter number of columns you want: "))
mat=[]
for m in range(row):
    a=[]
for n in range(col):
    a.append(0)
mat.append(a)

for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
        mat[i][j]=int(input("Input element: "))
print("Your Matrix is :",mat)
n = 3;
if (SaddlePoint(mat, n) ==
    False):
    print("No Saddle Po");
```

Comment: What is a saddle point?

Comment: You are using the `a` variable only once, to avoid future mistakes use a list comprehension: `mat = [[0] * col for _ in range(row)]` to initialize a matrix.